# Replacing multiple characters across multiple File names in a Unix folder

Tags: shell-script, shell, scripting

I have a couple of files in a Unix folder, let's say /home/TRANS.

Files are received within this folder on a monthly basis. File names are like:

- ENCD_213_E-DM_CCA_ID3490_A01.txt
- ENCD_213_E-DM_CCA_ID33120_A01.txt
- ENCD_213_E-DM_CCA_IDP3664_A01.txt
- ENCD_213_E-DM_CCA_ID3327_A01.txt
- ENACT_215_E_DM_CCA_IDA33320_25OCT2017.csv
- ENACT_215_E_DM_CCA_IDA31116_25OCT2017.csv

After renaming, the final output should be:

- id3490.txt
- id33120.txt
- idp3664.txt
- id3327.txt
- ida33320.csv
- ida31116.csv

So essentially, I want to have the following strings replaced across all file names within the TRANS folder, and make the final output filename as lowercase:

- ENCD_213_E-DM_CCA_
- _A01
- ENACT_215_E_DM_CCA_
- _25OCT2017

How can I execute this either in a single line command or as a shell script? I did check multiple questions but couldn't find replacement of multiple characters in addition to changing to lowercase. Need your help as I am pretty new to Unix.

Comment: are this parts `_213_` and `_215_` always fixed (the same) for all filenames?

Comment: That right Roman, _215_E_DM is always associated with the csv filesnames with date.

Comment: @NiCKz Hold on a sec and I'll add an explanation to my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this. Here is one command that should work for your example:

```
for oldname in *; do
    newname="$(echo "${oldname}" | grep -Po 'ID\w?\d+' | tr A-Z a-z).txt" \
    && mv -i "${oldname}" "${newname}";
done
```

That example used Perl-compatible regular-expressions which it appears your `grep` does not support. Here is an alternative using basic regular expressions:

```
for oldname in *; do
    newname="$(echo "${oldname}" | grep -o 'ID[A-Z]\?[0-9]\+' | tr A-Z a-z).txt" \
    && mv -i "${oldname}" "${newname}";
done
```

A more detailed explanation follows.

---

The expression `for oldname in *` uses a [globbing-pattern/wildcard](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm) to iterate over the files in your current directory and stores each name in the `oldname` variable. To test this you could run the following:

```
for oldname in *; do echo "${oldname}"; done
```

Then we use `grep` to extract the part of the file-name you want to keep. The `-P` option flag tells `grep` to use Perl-compatible regular expressions (not really necessary in this situation) and the `-o` flag tells `grep` to extract only the matching substring (instead of printing the entire string). The `\w?` pattern matches an option single character (a "word" character) and the `\d+` pattern matches one or more digits. We can test out the regular expression like this:

```
for oldname in *; do echo "${oldname}" | grep -Po 'ID\w?\d+'; done
```

Then we use `tr` to convert uppercase characters to lowercase:

```
for oldname in *; do echo "${oldname}" | grep -Po 'ID\w?\d+' | tr A-Z a-z; done
```

The next step is to use [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) to assign this string to a variable and then print the result:

```
for oldname in *; do
    newname="$(echo "${oldname}" | grep -Po 'ID\w?\d+' | tr A-Z a-z)" && echo "${newname}"
done
```

Then we add in the ".txt" file-extension:

```
for oldname in *; do
    newname="$(echo "${oldname}" | grep -Po 'ID\w?\d+' | tr A-Z a-z).txt" && echo "${newname}"
done
```

We can run this command as a sanity-check to make sure we're getting the expected results. Once we're satisfied we replace the `echo` command with a `mv` command:

```
for oldname in *; do
    newname="$(echo "${oldname}" | grep -Po 'ID\w?\d+' | tr A-Z a-z).txt" \
    && mv -i "${oldname}" "${newname}";
done
```

Comment: Thanks @igal. Can this be executed in the same command line? Would you mind adding an explanation of what each option does? Sorry, but I'm completely new and wanted to understand. A link may also help.

Comment: Also, is there a Preview option available for this command so that I can check before finally executing it to test in my folder? I saw in some of the posts that a -n option works as a preview, but not sure if it would with this one.

Comment: @NiCKz Check out my updated answer. I think it will address your concern. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: @NiCKz There's no general "dry run" flag that will work with every command. Some commands (e.g. rsync) have options like that, but it isn't typical.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.. very helpful. However, when I am executing this:
`for oldname in *; do echo "${oldname}" | grep -Po 'ID\w?\d+'; done`

I get this error message:
_grep: illegal option -- P_
_grep: illegal option -- o_

Also, I have some csv files that would need to be renamed, which has dates in them.

Comment: @Nick The unix commands can vary quite a bit. In this case it depends on which version of grep you have. You can get rid of the `-P` flag and used this instead: `grep -o 'ID[A-Z]\?[0-9]\+'`

Comment: @NiCKz If you want to match different patterns then you should probably update your question. In general, I strongly recommend learning about regular expressions. They're a really fundamental text-processing tool.

Answer (score 0):

**`find`** + **`bash`** solution:

```
find . -type f -regextype posix-egrep \
    -regex ".*EN(ACT|CD)_[0-9]+_E(-|_)DM_CCA_.+[0-9]\.(txt|csv)$" -exec bash -c \
    'fn=${0##*/}; dir_n="${0%/*}/"; 
    [[ "$fn" =~ .*_(ID[^_]+)_.*\.(txt|csv)$ ]]; 
    mv "$0" "$dir_n${BASH_REMATCH[1],,}.${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"; ' {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

For filename manipulation, bash parameter expansions are very nice.  See [this](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal) for a good overview.

Since you're basically wanting to preserve the ID part of the file, you can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *csv *txt; do
   ext="${f##*.}"

   if [[ $f =~ ID[[:alnum:]]+ ]]; then
      mv "$f" "${BASH_REMATCH,,}.${ext}"
   fi

done

exit
```

This loops over every csv and txt file and gets the extension using PE.  Then, use the bash regex match operator `=~` to check if the filename matches your pattern.  If it does, bash populates `$BASH_REMATCH` with the contents of the regex match.  Then, move the file to the lowercase version of this match, appending the original extension.  I created all of your example files and got the intended results.